# Finding a basis for a set of tuples

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

> Let $R^\infty$  be the subspace of U={${f:N→R}$} of “infinite tuples” which consist of all $f\in U$ such that f(i) = 0 for all but finitely many values of i. Define an inner product on  $R^\infty$ by (x, y) $=\sum_{i=1}^\infty xiyi$. Let $∥x − y∥$ be the metric on $R^\infty$. Find the basis of $R^\infty$ and prove the set of basis is closed, bounded, and noncompact.

This is a finite sum for the inner product according to the above definition of the subspace, since all but finitely many terms vanish. For the first part, I defined $e_i = (0,··· ,0,1,0,··· ,)$, where 1 appears on the ith slot and I think ei form a basis for $R^\infty.$ I am not sure how to show this set is the base though.

For the second part the set would be {${e_i : i ∈ N}$} but I thought a set is compact if it is closed and bounded but how can it be noncompact if it is closed and bounded?

Finally, what does it mean by a set of infinite tuples?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, if $f\in R^\infty$ you have 
$$
f=\sum_{j=1}^m f_j\,e_j. 
$$
So the $\{e_j\}$ span $R^\infty$. And they are linearly independent: if $f=\sum_{j=1}^m a_j e_i=0$, then $0=f(k)=a_k$ for all $k$.

It is **very** not true that "closed + bounded = compact". It is always true in finite dimension, and it not true in infinite dimension. The set $\{e_i\}$ is clearly non-compact, since it doesn't admit a convergent subsequence: you have $\|e_k-e_j\|=\sqrt2$ for all $k,j$.

Finally, all the above is talking about sequences. A sequence of real numbers is nothing other than a function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$. The usual sets in this context are

- $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$: the bounded sequences
- $c_0$: the sequences that converge to $0$
- $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$: the sequences $f$ with $\sum_j|f(j)|<\infty$
- $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$: the sequences $f$ with $\sum_j|f(j)|^2<\infty$
- etc.

The notation $R^\infty$ is unusual, but (even though it is ever present) there is no universally accepted notation for it

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation can you explain why it is closed then? a closed set can be defined as a set which contains all its limit points but there is no limit here since nothing converges

Comment: The set $\{e_j\}$ is closed because it consists of isolated points, all at fixed distance from each other. So its complement is open: if $x\not\in\{e_j\}$, then if $\|y-x\|<\sqrt2$ then $y\not\in\{e_j\}$. If you want to think of limit points, the limit points are precisely the $e_j$.

Comment: got it, why is the limit point say ej for some j for a sequence? I would imagine if ej is a limit point, then the sequence distance will be 2, .....,2,0,2....,2 but that would not converge? apologies if i got the definition confused

Comment: i would argue that there is no limit points in the set since every sequence is just a single point?

Comment: So, you are saying that a singleton (a set with a single point) is not closed?

Comment: so evrey single point is a sequence itself in this set? and no a singleton is closed im bad with definitions

Comment: For the same reason that a singleton is closed, a discrete set where all points are at more than a fixed distance from the others, is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you've got a slight notational weirdness: $e_i$ should really be a function. It's clear what function you mean, but mixing notations is odd. Instead, define $$e_i(n) = \cases{1, & n = i\\ 0, & \text{otherwise}}$$

You can check that it is a basis directly: for any $f \in U$, we have $f = \sum_i f(i)e_i$, since for all $n$, we have $f(n) = f(n)e_n(n) = \sum_i f(i)e_i(n)$ (where in the first equality, we're multiplying by $1$, and in the second, we're adding $0$).

> I thought a set is compact if it is closed and bounded but how can it be noncompact if it is closed and bounded?

This is true for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Your set (which I'll call $X$) clearly is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I rather suspect that this exercise is here purely to point out that said equivalence does not hold outside of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The bound on $X$ is simple: $\|e_i\| = \sum_j e_i(j)^2 = e_i(i)^2 = 1$ for all $i$.

To see that $X$ is closed, first show that $\|e_i - e_j\| = 2$ for all $i \neq j$, and so the only convergent sequences in $X$ are the eventually constant sequences.

To see that $X$ is not compact, define $A_i$ to be the open $1$-ball around $e_i$ in $U$ for all $i$. This gives, after intersecting with $X$, an open cover of $X$ (clearly each $A_i$ is open in $U$, so its intersection with $X$ is open in $X$, and clearly it's a cover, as each $e_i$ lies in $A_i$. But $\{A_i\}$ has no finite subcover - indeed, by what we did to show that $X$ is closed, we see that the $A_i$ are disjoint, and so $\{A_i\}$ has no proper subcovers at all, so certainly has no finite ones. Thus, $X$ is not compact.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation but can you explain what you mean by closed "eventually constant sequences" and how that has to do with limit points being contained in the set (hence closed)?

Comment: The limit points of the set are the limit points of the convergent sequences in the set. The only convergent sequences in the set are the ones that look like $([\text{some junk}],\ldots, e_i,e_i,e_i,\ldots,[\text{more }e_i\text{ forever}])$ where we've got some collection of stuff, then just lots of $e_i$s forever. The limit of that sequences is obviously $e_i$, which lies in the set, so the set contains all of its limit points, so is closed.